# Remove all occurrences of _# from xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to remove any value that ends with _# (i.e. _1, _2, etc.). The XSLT I have coded right now is not the greatest as I have to specify the exact path of the node that might contain the values _1 and _2.

How can I go about in updating any node in the XML that contains a _#? At the moment I have to create a logic to specifically look for nodes securityDisplayLabel and displayLabel

XML:

```
<trades>
    <tradeBody>
        <bond>
            <securityId>
                <securityAlternateCodes/>
                <securityLabel>179965</securityLabel>
                <securityMarket>CAD QC</securityMarket>
                <securityDisplayLabel>Q 3.5 120148_1</securityDisplayLabel>
            </securityId>
            **<displayLabel>Q 3.5 120148_1</displayLabel>**
        </bond>
    </tradeBody>
</trades>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="secDispLab">
    <xsl:value-of select="/MxML/trades/trade/tradeBody/*/securityId/securityDisplayLabel" />
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:variable name="stringAfterUnderscore">
    <xsl:call-template name="lastUnderscore">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$secDispLab" />
        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'_'" />
    </xsl:call-template>      
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <securities>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/MxML/trades/trade/tradeBody/*/securityId" />
        </securities>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="trades/trade/tradeBody/*/securityId">
    <xsl:call-template name="loadData">
        <xsl:with-param name="dataClass" select="'security'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="queryBy" select="'ID'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="dataValue" select="concat(./securityMarket,';',./securityLabel)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="securityId/securityDisplayLabel">
    <securityDisplayLabel>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number($stringAfterUnderscore)">
                <xsl:variable name="numberLength">
                    <xsl:value-of select="string-length($stringAfterUnderscore)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="labelLength">
                    <xsl:value-of select="string-length($secDispLab)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($secDispLab, 1, ($labelLength - ($numberLength + 1))) "/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="@stringAfterUnderscore"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </securityDisplayLabel>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="lastUnderscore">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $delimiter)">
            <xsl:call-template name="lastUnderscore">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of 
              select="$string" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "remove any value" is ambiguous. What is the expected result of processing the given example?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove any **element** whose text node ends with an underscore followed by a single digit, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[translate(substring(text(), string-length(text()) -1), '123456789', '000000000') = '_0']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```